# Array is empty after calling method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

everytime I call the method `-(void)setArrayCheckOut:(int)num` in another class the array `arrayCheckout` is empty. Calling `-(IBAction)reloadTable:(id)sender` after `-(void)setArrayCheckOut:(int)num` "results in reload table - (null), 0".

Any idea what goes wrong?

so long

```
@implementation CheckOut
-(id)init
{
[super init];
tableCheckOut = [[NSTableView alloc]init];
if (!arrayCheckOut)
{
arrayCheckOut = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrayCheckOut addObject:@"-"];
}

return self;
     }
-(void)setArrayCheckOut:(int)num
{

  switch (num) {
 case 170:
 [arrayCheckOut addObject:@"T20, T20, DB"];
 break;
 default:
 [arrayCheckOut addObject:@"-"];
 break;
   }
 NSLog(@"array = %@",[arrayCheckOut objectAtIndex:0]);

[tableCheckOut reloadData];

}


-(IBAction)reloadTable:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"reload table - %@, %d",[arrayCheckOut objectAtIndex:0],[arrayCheckOut count]);

[tableCheckOut reloadData];
}


- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv
{
return [arrayCheckOut count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tColumn
 row:(int)row
{
NSString *v = [arrayCheckOut objectAtIndex:row];
return v;
}
 @end
```

Comment: where is arrayCheckOut defined? Show the code.

Comment: Nowhere because I don't need it. The array will only read by the application and deleted completly before I fill it up again.

Comment: Problems with `setArrayCheckOut:` include a magic number (170), magic and un-localized string literals, use of `int` where `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` might be more appropriate (also a problem in your data source methods), and the non-descriptive name of the method. I suggest defining constants for the number and strings, localizing the strings using `NSLocalizedString` (since they seem to be intended for display to the user), switching to `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger`, and renaming `setArrayCheckOut:` to something that more clearly states the method's goal, rather than just its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array were empty, `objectAtIndex:0` would throw an exception.

Since it doesn't, but returns `nil`, you don't have an array: You have sent the `objectAtIndex:` message to `nil`.

Most probably, `CheckOut` is not the sort of class whose instances are initialized by `init`. Check the documentation for its superclass to see what its designated initializer is, then override that instead.

Comment: I'm new to programming...  What kind auf initializer should I use? The superclass is NSObject so I expected there is only one initializer (init).

Comment: You should implement whatever initializer will be called. The only initializer NSObject provides is `init`, so that's probably the one you need to implement in your subclass; since you have implemented it to create the array, that returns us to the question of why you don't have an array. Did you omit from your question some code that sets the `arrayCheckOut` variable back to `nil`?

Comment: Grepped the content of my project. arrayCheckOut is only defined in CheckOut.h/m. So here's my whole project including all sourcefiles: http://stubbi.org/Darx.zip. You can see, `arrayCheckOut` is correctly set but the table isn't refreshed with the new value. `arrayCheckOut` got its default value again. Perhaps you find the mistake

Comment: Calling  `[self setArrayCheckOut:170]` in `-(IBAction)reloadTable:(id)sender` returns the expected result. The array is written and persistent. But why I can't call the method from another class, where I initiliazed an object from CheckOut?

Comment: One problem you have is that you are creating one instance of `Checkout` in the xib and a second one in the `x01` class.

Remove the `cOut` initialization from `x01`'s init method, change `cOut` to be an IBOutlet and then connect it to the instance of `Checkout` in MainMenu.xib.