# array has 10 nil objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

So I have four types of arrays,

```
@property NSMutableArray *snowImageArray;
@property NSMutableArray *dogImageArray;
@property NSMutableArray *catImageArray;
@property NSMutableArray *rabbitImageArray;
```

these arrays store custom objects like standardURL, username,etc . I then created another array called

```
  @property NSMutableArray *allImageArray;
```

where I stored the four object arrays in the allImageArray. I want to populate the allImageArray in a collection view.. so far I have this in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method... i looped through the array like this..

```
NSArray *allImageArray = [self.allImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",allImageArray);
        for (NSMutableArray *searchDataImage in allImageArray) {
        for (ImageHelper *imageHelper in searchDataImage) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageHelper.standardPhotoURL];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }
```

now for some reason the allImageArray has 10 objects that literally have nothing in them it prints 10 objects that has @"0 objects".. i instantiated my allImageArray in the viewDidLoad. I also double checked my methods and made sure i only did this four times for dog, snow, rabbit & cat:

```
             [self.rabbitImageArray addObject:imageHelper]; //adds the objects to the array
             [self.allImageArray addObject:self.rabbitImageArray];
             [self.tableView reloadData]
```

please tell me what i did wrong? :/

Comment: self.rabbitImageArray is init-ed ? From what I see you just only add objects to it, but if it's not init-ed it will be always nil

Comment: That is correct. And any messages sent to `nil` will be just ignored, and if a return value is expected 0 will be returned (`nil` if an object is expected). That is why the "array" seems to be returning `nil ` objects with `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array is empty after calling method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847860/array-is-empty-after-calling-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to initialize arrays before adding objects:

```
self.snowImageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
self.dogImageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
self.catImageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
self.rabbitImageArray = [NSMutableArray  new];

self.allImageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: still tried this it doesn't work.. keep in mind i am using AFNetworking to populate my arrays. the arrays contain custom objects..if i let it crash this is the error i receive [ImageHelper countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17004c3f0

Comment: instead of NSLog(@"%@",allImageArray);  try to iterate like this: for(id obj in [allImageArray allValues]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}

Answer (score 1):

Alway allocate memory for array. 
`self.snowImageArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];`
or
`self.snowImageArray = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: @Jenel, what happens in your code is that you add object to a nil object. In Objective-C you can send messages (call mehtods) on nil objects. They will result in a nop and return 0 or nil respectively. So your code is executed without any equivalent of a nullpointer exception but the result is not what you expect. This is typical for Objective-C and will happen to you more often in the future.

Comment: here is more snippet for my code .. i used exception breakpoints and it breaks at  for (ImageHelper *imageHelper in searchDataImage) .... the allImageArray contains 10 objects that have 0
        NSMutableArray *allImageArray = [self.allImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",allImageArray);
        for (NSMutableArray *searchDataImage in allImageArray) {
        for (ImageHelper *imageHelper in searchDataImage) {

Comment: Where you allocate them?

Answer (score 0):

So all the answers are somewhat correct, I had already allocated memory for all the arrays.

I am currently trying to display each array in a table view cell, and inside the tableview cell I have a collection view.. the problem with my code was that one of the arrays in my allImagesArray was empty. so what I did was added

```
 if (self.allImageArray.count == 4) {
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

to UITableViewCell:cellForRowAtIndexPath method. this makes sure that there are a total of 4 arrays. none of them being empty.